# Question about quicksort and its worst-case time complexity assuming you choose the middle pivot for each partitioning level

Tags: algorithm, big-o, quicksort

So if you pick a pivot that is either the smallest or largest element this results in the next call being of size n - 1. So if you repeat this getting size n - 2, n - 3 and so on you get the worst-case time complexity for quicksort, this being O(n^2).

The thing is, to get this pattern of n - 1, n - 2, n - 3 etc. you always need to pick a bad pivot, meaning the pivot always needs to be the largest or smallest element. My question is, assuming you would always pick the middle pivot, what ordering of, for eg. `{2, 3, 1, 6, 5, 7}` would yield a quadratic complexity?

Through some testing, I discovered that `{4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1}` seems to follow the worst-case pattern (again always choosing the middle pivot) up until the call n - 2, where it splits into an even and uneven partition. From what I understand the time complexity can be defined by the sum of the complexities at each partitioning level. So I wanted to know is if `{4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1}` still generates the worst-case time complexity even though it does not follow the n - 1 pattern all the way through, and if it doesn't generate the worst-case time complexity how would I approach finding an ordering of a sequence of sorted integers; with the restriction that I always choose the middle pivot; that does.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this problem for quite a bit!

Comment: @MrSmith42 There are ways to always choose a good pivot without increasing *asymptotic* complexity (e.g. median of medians). The real-world performance will suffer though.

Comment: You choose the middle pivot, but the choice of pivot position does not change the complexity, it can only make the analysis harder. Choose the first element and try an array that is already sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the question's method, and assuming pivot = array[(lo+hi)/2], then for a pattern where the pivot is the smallest element, one sequence is decreasing even numbers followed by increasing odd numbers:

```
{6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7}
 6  4  2  3  5  7
 6  4  3  5  7
 6  4  5  7
 6  5  7
 6  7
 7
```